# Using SCOPE_IDENTITY result in another query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having difficulties with this code

```
EXECUTE Environment.dbo.psu_some_psu

@instanceId = 1
,@serverId = 2
,@ip = '111.111.111.111'
,@clientName = 'dev-contact'
,@applicationId = 9
,@accountId = 35
,@userID = 22

DECLARE @restoreId INT
SET @restoreId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

UPDATE Environment.dbo.restore_requests
SET Status = 1
WHERE Id = @restoreId
```

The stored procedure insert a row with indentity and with a status by default.
After the execution of the stored procedure i use scope_identity to get the ID of the inserted row.
But i cant get the update to work, i think there is a problem with the WHERE condition.

Thanks

Comment: you need the stored procedure to return the scope_identity. Your code cannot see it because it stays in  your stored procedure

Comment: I don't recommend doing it that way. Use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`  within the Stored Procedure and use an `OUTPUT` parameter to return the value to the calling SQL.

Comment: Ok ! I've just think about that ! I'm gonna try that and let you know !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](http://SCOPE_IDENTITY) because it returns the last identity value inserted *in the current scope* - and since each procedure has it's own scope - you do not get the expected results.

> Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger, function, or batch. Therefore, if two statements are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch, they are in the same scope.

Use an output parameter to return the `scope_identity()` from inside the procedure that actually executes the `insert` statement.

Also, please note that if you are inserting multiple records, the `scope_identity()` will return only the last value - in such cases you use the [`output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause on the `insert` statement to get a table containing all the newly inserted identity values.

```
DECLARE @MyTableVar table( NewScrapReasonID smallint,  
                           Name varchar(50),  
                           ModifiedDate datetime);  
INSERT Production.ScrapReason  
    OUTPUT INSERTED.ScrapReasonID, INSERTED.Name, INSERTED.ModifiedDate  
        INTO @MyTableVar  
VALUES (N'Operator error', GETDATE());
```

Comment: Use `OUTPUT` always.  Don't use the other functions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff why prefer the `output` clause over `scope_identity()` when you are inserting a single row?

Comment: . . Because it is safe.  It does what is intended.  Using a function or variable just brings in unnecessary issues regarding locking and sessions and users and the number of rows.  `OUTPUT` simply returns the modified rows.

Comment: I'm using output and it works when i execute all the code in once. But when i executed the update after the stored procedure, it says that i must declare my OUTPUT variable

Comment: @MatthieuRigaux The output clause is a part of the insert statement. You need to use that to get the identity value, then return it from the stored procedure as an output parameter.